# Empty the log file every time I write with Enterprise Library Logging

Tags: enterprise-library-6

I have Enterprise Library Logging used in my project which is working fine, but I need only the last entry to be saved at any time. Is there any configuration for that?

Below is my current configuration.

```
 <add name="WorkflowListener" formatter="Workflow Formatter" fileName="..\@data\logs\Workflow_log.txt" timeStampPattern="yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss" rollFileExistsBehavior="Overwrite" rollInterval="None" header="" footer="" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```